# Is there a formula for updating cells based on words or multiple words?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a sheet that tracks orders that we put in and we just started recently doing a breakdown on a month to month basis.

We have a main order log, main order log count, monthly order count, and a formula sheet

I currently have all my formulas for all the totals in the formula sheet and they then read into the main and monthly order log counts for a more streamlined approach so that way I can present it easier.

I have setup in my formula log a couple months already in advance the formulas to start counting each order when the new month hit but I have to go in manually each month and update where the totals will be reading from. Is there a way to automate it so instead of me going in each month and changing the locations of the formulas.

Say for instance I can type April in the heading and all my total formula cells will populate for the criteria I set for April and so on?

I would more than happy to share screenshots if needed I just cant share the sheet. But I would love to learn if possible.

I cant seem to grasp which formula I could use.

Comment: I am using Google Sheets.

Comment: share a copy /sample of your sheet with example of desired output